# Delete max heap method

Tags: c, heap

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 10

void swap(int * a , int * b);

int parent(int i){
    return  ((i+1)/2)-1;
}


int left(int i){
    return  2*(i+1)-1;
}


int right(int i){
    return  (2*(i+1)+1)-1;
}

int printHeap(int *heap, int pos){
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<pos;i++){
     printf("%d ",heap[i]);
     }
     printf("----\n");   
}

int insert(int *heap,int *pos, int value)
{
    int i=*pos;
    int tmp;
    heap[i]=value;
    (*pos)++;
    while(parent(i)>=0) {
       if(heap[parent(i)]<heap[i]){
          tmp=heap[parent(i)];
          heap[parent(i)]=heap[i];
          heap[i]=tmp;                                          
       }else{
             break;     
       }                    
       i=parent(i);
    } 

}

void deleteMax(int *heap,int *pos)
{
    int tmp;
    heap[0]=heap[*pos-1];
    (*pos)--;
    maxHeapify(heap,&pos);
}

void maxHeapify(int *heap,int *pos)
{
    int i=*pos,l=left(i),r=right(i),max;
    if (l<i && heap[l]>heap[i])
        max=l;
    else
        max=i;

    if(r<i && heap[r]>heap[max])
        max=r;

    if (max!=i)
    {
        swap(&heap[i],&heap[max]);
        maxHeapify(heap,max);
    }
}

void swap(int * a , int * b)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int heap[n];
    int pos=0;
    insert(heap,&pos, 10);
    insert(heap,&pos, 5);
    insert(heap,&pos, 15);
    insert(heap,&pos, 35);
    insert(heap,&pos, 66);
    insert(heap,&pos, 41);
    insert(heap,&pos, 42);
    insert(heap,&pos, 21);
    insert(heap,&pos, 14);
    insert(heap,&pos, 3);
    printHeap(heap,pos);
    deleteMax(heap,&pos);
    printHeap(heap,pos);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I have this heap implementation and I want to delete maximum heap (heap[0]) and then fix down the whole array , first I replace the max heap with the last element (min) and then I try to fix the structure with the maxHeapify method but I it seems something is wrong , any idea? thank you in advance!

Comment: That `#define n 10` is scary :( Are you sure you don't intend on using that letter anywhere else?

Comment: I dont think I used it again it is just array size, then I use pos

Comment: What is the second printHeap call displaying ?

Comment: This line: maxHeapify(heap,&pos); is taking a pointer to a pointer to integer.  The function maxHeapify() is treating this pointer to a pointer to integer as if it were only a pointer to integer.  Suggest removing the '&' from that invokation of maxheapify().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put maxHeapify in a loop like this:

```
void BuildMaxHeap(int* arr)
{
    for( int i =  9; i >= 0; i-- )
        maxHeapify( arr, &i );
}

void maxHeapify( int* arr, int *pos )
{

    int i = *pos;
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;
    int largest = i;

    if( left < n && arr[ left ] > arr[ largest ] )
        largest = left;
    if( right < n && arr[ right ] > arr[ largest ] )
        largest = right;
    if( largest != i )
    {
        int temp = arr[ i ];
        arr[ i ] = arr[ largest ];
        arr[ largest ] = temp;
        maxHeapify( arr, &largest );
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, but then I made your code more readable.  I'll post my maxHeapify

Comment: Since maxHeapify is already a recursive function, I doubt invoking it repeatedly will help solve the problem.

Comment: I tested it with your data. Use it or don't. *shrug*